# Elastic Beanstalk: Deploy Nodejs status Degraded Following services are not running: web

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I just use `eb deploy` and also tried upload with zip, the elatic beanstalk environment show "degraded".

The log when I click in to see is

```
Overall 
Degraded

Impaired services on all instances.

Severe
Following services are not running: web.
```

My app.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Sever console log.")
});
```

package.json content

```
{
  "name": "project_api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.18.3"
  },
  "description": "the server side of the api",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Businsoft Limited",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dropbox": "^5.2.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

I think this is the simpliest start with Elastic Beanstalk, but somehow it fails. Any idea to solve it?

Answer (score 6):

After debug for a while, I managed to figure out the issue.

In `package.json`

I need to remove this line:

```
"main": "app.js",
```

And the add the "start" in the "scripts" like this:

```
"scripts":
  "start": "node app.js"
```

And then update the

```
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Sever console log.")
});
```

to

```
const port = process.env.port || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Sever console log.")
});
```

And then go to AWS Console > Elastic Beanstalk's environment > Configuration > Software Edit > add a properties at Environment properties

Name `port` Value `8080`

Finally reupload the source code, and it works.